# Zend_Pdf :Issues with array of image path

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, zend-pdf, magento-1.7

I have to generate Pdf of images. I have tried the following code

```
  public function getPdf($paths)
 {
   try {
  $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 
  for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
   {
   $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($paths[$i]);  
    $page->drawImage($image, 20, 20, 50, 46);
    $pdf->pages[] = $page;
   }
   $pdf->save('document.pdf');
     echo 'SUCCESS: Document saved!';
    } catch (Zend_Pdf_Exception $e) {
     die ('PDF error: ' . $e->getMessage());  
     } catch (Exception $e) {
     die ('Application error: ' . $e->getMessage());    
    }
   }
```

Please note that $paths is an array which contains correct physical paths like C:/wamp/www/magento1.7/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/o/portf1.jpg.... Now the problem is that it is not able to create Pdf and throws exception saying "PDF error: Cannot create image resource. File not found". Can anybody helps me in this or simply point out what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not have required permissions. Look if file [is_readable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) and if not try [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) it.
You can also always change file permissions on your windows.

Edit1: Change your code:

```
$numPaths = count($paths);
for($i=0; $i < $numPaths; $i++) {
..
```

Comment: No it generates PDF with image, when I give C:/wamp/www/magento1.7/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/o/portf1.jpg statically to  $image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath();...

Comment: Can you please var_dump $path variable, and update answer with output.

Comment: It displays like  array
  0 => string 'C:/wamp/www/magento1.7/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/o/portf1.jpg' (length=112)
  1 => string 'C:/wamp/www/magento1.7/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/a/landf1.jpg' (length=112)

array
  0 => string 'C:/wamp/www/magento1.7/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/p/o/portf1.jpg' (length=112)
  1 => string 'C:/wamp/www/magento1.7/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/l/a/landf1.jpg' (length=112)

Comment: I assume you dublicated var_dump, because there is only two files, another think i noticed that your for loop interating 5 elements while your array have only two, i have updated answer.